# Unable to click on the webelement in IE10 in selenum webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, internet-explorer-10

I am facing issue in clicking on a `webelement` in IE 10, the web element can be identified only by `linktext` or using `xpath` as `//b[text()='abc']`

The length of the text is more than 15 characters, I tried using partial link text.

In console it displayed as 'clicked on the element' but actually it does not click.

Comment: Can you provide the `html` and also the test code you have tried with?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the `b` element would be really clickable. Most likely it is the *parent of `b`*:

```
//*[b[contains(.,'abc')]]
```

or:

```
//b[contains(.,'abc')]/..
```